# VueJS Dynamic Style Binding?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a data property set on a Vueity Card called `editMode`. When I click on the button the `editMode` is set to true and an icon shows up on the `v-img`. Now how can I make it so that when the `editMode` is true,  the `opacity` of the image is set to `0.3` but the icon stays unaffected?

Here is the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/WNQZGGz?editors=1010)

Please check the code below:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      editMode: false
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" dark>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-card>
            <v-img :style="editMode ? 'opacity: 0.3' : ''" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/desert.jpg" aspect-ratio="2.75">
              <v-container v-if="editMode">
                <v-layout align-center justify-center row fill-height>
                  <v-icon class="mt-5" color="white" large>create</v-icon>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
            </v-img>
          </v-card>
          <v-btn large @click="editMode = !editMode"> Edit Mode </v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Right now the opacity of the icon also goes to 0.3. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution: Use class instead of style:

```
<v-img :class="{'editMode': editMode}" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/desert.jpg" aspect-ratio="2.75">
```

and in styles:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.editMode {
  ::v-deep .v-image__image {
      opacity: .3
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but when i use this with scoped styles, the styles don't seem to take affect?

Comment: Are you using scss?

Comment: `<style scoped>
  .editMode .v-image__image {
  opacity: .3;
  }
</style>`

Comment: nevermind, i moved my css into a separate css folder and it worked. I guess it doesn't like scoped.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could have used deep selectors but not worth it for a small issue.